# Replicating Lidar lite what emitter to use?

Tags: infrared, distance

So, I am not advocating or trying to copy or in any way infringe on the copyright that Lidar lite is based on. That being said I would like to use something like lidar lite for a distance sensing project (Basically an rc self driving). Now I haven't found any sensors that really are in my price range, less than 100 dollars, so I was thinking I could maybe home brew together something that is at least partially functional. But Lidar lite is no longer available and there isn't really a lot of info on how to do something like that. What research can I look into to make something like it. I have been experimenting with some ir emitters and receivers but haven't had any really good results. I also know that frequency modulation is a good idea since it will give the lidar a unique signature. But past that I am not really sure what to build. Is this way out of the realm of possibility or can it be done? **My main question is what IR emitter to use in order to determine the distance of an object at least 40 metres away outside.**

Comment: Have you considered looking up LIDAR patents?

Comment: I read through the lidar lite patent. It gave me some information but I don't have enough experience to know how to replicate it. Although I suspect it's too vague to really replicate.

Comment: LIDAR is older than that. Keep looking.

Comment: Ah I found some more interesting stuff that has more useful information. But one question I sorta left out is how do I know what emitter to use? There are many different types of IR emitters and I am unsure of which to use.

Comment: Now see, *that* is a decent question to ask.

Comment: I made it more clear so hopefully the crux of the question is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no worry about recreating a commercially available product if it is for your own use, and not part of a business enterprise. Furthermore, if Lidar Lite is no longer available the company clearly is not going to come after you, and there is no reason in the world not to use their ideas for your own enjoyment.

There is no simple answer to your question. A laser is the obvious choice for the emitter, and a silicon photodiode for the receiver. However, the laser is favored primarily because it's relatively easy to produce a small beam. If you're willing to spend more effort on optics, an LED is certainly possible.

Since you're obviously not very experienced, I'd recommend one of two approaches. At 40 meters, round trip for light is about 260 nsec. Call it 300 to give yourself some leeway. If you want to operate at longer ranges, assume a longer delay, but for now let's go with 300 nsec. A square wave at 3.3 MHz will have a 300 nsec period, so use half that frequency, or 1.65 MHz. What you want to do is exclusive OR the transmit and receive signals, and analyze the result. Alternatively, you can do what the commercial rangefinders do. Invert the receive signal and use it to drive the transmitter. The result (assuming you have adequate signal-to-noise) will be a square wave with period proportional to distance. Either approach will work, although you haven't specified your minimum range, and the second approach will not work well at close range due to the high frequencies involved.

I suggest you read [this Lidar Lite paper](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/lidarlite2_overview.pdf)  and pay attention to things like the bandpass filter they use. If you're going to be using your unit in sunlight, be aware that you need a very narrow filter to avoid your detector getting saturated.

If you avoid the correlation technique Lidar light used you'll work at much lower frequencies although you'll need to be careful to get fine resolution. You haven't specified your requirements, but presumably at 40 meters you're not interested in very fine measurements. You clearly have a great deal of learning and experience waiting for you. Good luck.

Comment: The radar equation is valid for lidar too. If the used laser or LED has enough power for a distance of 10 m, 20 m distance would require 16 times more power and 40 m 256 times. This problem is called the tyranny of the radar equation.

Comment: @Uwe - Sorry, but you're using the wrong version. This is presumably a resolved target, so power only goes up as the square of the distance.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I am not sure if I fully understand what you are getting at but I think I can figure it out. So, I have a 850 nm laser diode module and driver circuit. I know it works because I can see the beam when pointing a camera directly at the diode. But if I point it at where the beam should end I see nothing. Is this a problem with my camera, setup or something else?

Comment: @trinityalps - without knowing the laser power, I can't tell. But try this: put the laser within a few inches of a wall, and point the laser at it. Can you see the spot with the camera? If yes, move the laser away from the wall. At some point the spot should become invisible.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I tried that. Even at point blank range it doesn't show up. Also it's 5mW.